# Merging Pandas DataFrames (LEFT join style) produces strange results

Tags: python, pandas

*Please find the **summary** of this question and the actual full **data** at the bottom.*

I'm trying to merge two Pandas DataFrames with a many-to-one relationship.
This is normally a rather straightforward SQL-like procedure using a `LEFT` join, however I'm getting a rather unexpected result.

One DataFrame contains a list of drug names and their ingredients (left side) together with some extra information (an irrelevant ID and the company who makes the drugs), the other contains a list of ingredients and their numeric IDs (right side).

Obviously, what I like to get is a merged DataFrame where the ID of each ingredient is listed next to the ingredient name and, considering this is a many-to-one scenario, some IDs will get repeated as some drugs use the same ingredient.

A contrived example of both DataFrames (index omitted for brevity):

Drugs (df1):

```bash
someid  name       ingredient               company
1       Antivert   meclizine hydrochloride  Drug and Co
2       Antivert   meclizine hydrochloride  Pharma Inc
3       Antivert   meclizine hydrochloride  Medicine Limited
4       Antizol    fomepizole               Drug and Co
5       Antizol    fomepizole               Medicine Limited
6       Anzeme     toxyphenonium bromide    Pharma Inc 
7       Anzemet    toxyphenonium bromide    Drug and Co
...        ...
[51397 rows x 4 columns]
```

Ingredients (df2):

```bash
ingredient                id
meclizine hydrochloride   1
fomepizole                2
toxyphenonium bromide     3
...                       ...
[3354 rows x 2 columns]
```

To do the merge I simply do the following:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='ingredient', how='left')
```

The *expected* output is:

```bash
someid  name       ingredient               company           id
1       Antivert   meclizine hydrochloride  Drug and Co       1
2       Antivert   meclizine hydrochloride  Pharma Inc        1
3       Antivert   meclizine hydrochloride  Medicine Limited  1
4       Antizol    fomepizole               Drug and Co       2
5       Antizol    fomepizole               Medicine Limited  2
6       Anzeme     toxyphenonium bromide    Pharma Inc        3
7       Anzemet    toxyphenonium bromide    Drug and Co       3
...        ...
[51397 rows x 5 columns]
```

However, the actual output is:

```bash
someid  name       ingredient               company           id
1       Antivert   meclizine hydrochloride  Drug and Co       1
2       Antivert   meclizine hydrochloride  Pharma Inc        2
3       Antivert   meclizine hydrochloride  Medicine Limited  3
4       Antizol    fomepizole               Drug and Co       4
5       Antizol    fomepizole               Medicine Limited  5
6       Anzeme     toxyphenonium bromide    Pharma Inc        6
7       Anzemet    toxyphenonium bromide    Drug and Co       7
...        ...
[3354 rows x 5 columns]
```

Two important things to notice here:

- The `id` column simply counts up and IDs are not repeated.
- The amount of rows is now limited to how many rows there are in the ingredients (df2) DataFrame (3354).

The `info()` on both DataFrames shows me that both `ingredient` columns are of the same type (just to exclude comparison problems):

Drugs (df1):

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 51397 entries, 0 to 51396
Data columns (total 4 columns):
someid        51397 non-null int64
name          51397 non-null object
ingredient    51397 non-null object
company       51397 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 1.2+ MB
None
```

Ingredients (df2):

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3354 entries, 0 to 3353
Data columns (total 2 columns):
id            3354 non-null int64
ingredient    3354 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 78.6+ KB
None
```

Now for the interesting part. In an attempt to find out where this might be going wrong, I tried to do the merge on only a subset of both DataFrames using `head()`:

```
df1 = df1.head(100)
df2 = df2.head(100)
```

If I then perform the merge I get the desired output without a problem, just only 100 rows. If I keep increasing the amount of rows to take for `head()`, even up to the point that it is way more than the number of rows present, the output is still perfect. This, for example, works perfectly:

```
df1 = df1.head(100000)
df2 = df2.head(100000)
```

Notice that I include the first 100.000 rows (only 53.000 in df1). This too will give me the expected merge output.

Interesting bit: after including a large amount of rows with `head(100000)`, only the info for the Drugs DataFrame (df1) alters slightly:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 51397 entries, 0 to 51396
Data columns (total 4 columns):
someid        51397 non-null int64
name          51397 non-null object
ingredient    51397 non-null object
company       51397 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 2.0+ MB
None
```

Notice the memory usage went up from 1.2 MB to 2.0 MB. Yet besides that, they both still are DataFrame objects with the same structure as before I pulled them through that operation.

What might be going on here? Why does the merge produce such strange results, unless I pull the DataFrames through `head()` first?

---

**To summarize:** Without using `head()` the `merge()` output is showing reduced rows (# rows = # right side rows) and each ingredient ID is simply "pasted" on there in a serial manner. However, if I do use `head()`, even with a great enough number to include all rows on both sides, the join works as expected.

Python version: 2.7.10 - Pandas version: 0.17.1 - NumPy version: 1.10.1

---

**Full data:** For the ones wanting to try with the exact same data, I created two gists on Github that contain the full data (dictionary form) for both the drugs and the ingredients DataFrame mentioned above.

- Drugs: [gist](https://gist.github.com/Timusan/07d50c8a2cb3b186af4c)
- Ingredients: [gist](https://gist.github.com/Timusan/728086b1ce5ea309007d)

They are exported using `DataFrame.to_dict()` and can be imported/transformed back into a DataFrame using `DataFrame.from_dict(data)`.

Comment: I have `3.4.3, 0.17.1, 1.10.1` respectively and everything works fine.. Are your `someid` and `ingredient` indices or it's just first columns?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov These are indeed just the first columns, for brevity I excluded the indices from the listing.

Comment: page not found for your data...

Comment: Yes ... just found out Github has hidden my account for it thinks I am not human for some reason ... nice timing. Contacted their support ... *bleep* *bloop*

Comment: Okay, Github issue resolved, links should work again.